# Does InnoDB behind the scenes ALSO use table locks?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

Connection1:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT *
FROM world.city
WHERE ID = 130
FOR SHARE;
```

Connection2:

```
SELECT engine, thread_id, object_schema,
object_name, lock_type, lock_mode,
lock_status, lock_data
FROM performance_schema.data_locks;


+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| engine | thread_id | object_schema | object_name | lock_type | lock_mode     | lock_status | lock_data |
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| INNODB |       130 | world         | city        | TABLE     | IS            | GRANTED     | NULL      |
| INNODB |       130 | world         | city        | RECORD    | S,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 130       |
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I get a **table lock** and a record lock.
I knew InnoDB used **ONLY record level blocks**.

Comment: What will you be using the `FOR SHARE` for?

Comment: Hi @Rick James for nothing concrete actually, I'm really studying locks in MySQL. It struck me as odd that there were 2 types of locking in innodb when it says it only does row level locking. But now I think I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Innodb sets [intention locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks) (IS) on tables:

> Intention locks are table-level locks that indicate which type of lock (shared or exclusive) a transaction requires later for a row in a table.

Comment: Hi @Shadow, thanks, so the table level locks from the layer above (the MySQL ones) do not appear in this performance_schema.data_locks table? I thought the lock_type = TABLE in this table were the MySQL OWN ones.

Comment: Locks at the MySQL table level (the top layer) are always IMPLICIT regardless of the engine, right?

Comment: Mysql only provides table locks via lock table statement. You did not issue such statement, so you do not see them in the result of your lock query.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, +1, I thought LOCK STATEMENT was InnoDB's own, that's why in InnoDB it is not recommended to use LOCK STATEMENT, right?

Comment: You can lock table to lock myisam tables as well. The implementation details may be storage engine specific.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shadow, one last question to CORONATE THIS GREAT ANSWER, does the concept of shared lock/exclusive lock "still exist-effective" ONLY that INNODB applies it at ROW LEVEL instead of "FULL" TABLE LEVEL, right? I already marked it as best answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question!

Comment: does the exclusive lock/shared lock used by innodb apply at row level "instead of table level"? @Shadow

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The table level lock is intention lock only.

Comment: "Yes, that's correct. The table level lock is intention lock only" - hi @Shadow, so, Does an IS/IX "split into 2"? That is, does the IX/IS apply to THE TABLE ITSELF but the shared lock/exclusive lock applies ONLY to the row? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Performance schema pulls data from the buffer pool and not disk. If it can not find the page in the pool it will report the lock_data column as NULL.

See https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/innodb-data-locking-part-2-5-locks-deeper-dive/